# How do you find the scalar field of the vector field $F=-y\hat{i}+x\hat{j}$

Tags: vectors, vector-fields, scalar-fields

I know that:

$F=\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\hat{i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\hat{j}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\hat{k}$

So in cases like:

$F=2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}$

I just integrate each term to get:

$f=x^2+y^2$

But when I do the same process for this:

$F=-y\hat{i}+x\hat{j}$

I get:

$f=-xy+xy = 0$

Which seems wrong.

I know that $F=-y\hat{i}+x\hat{j}$ is the vector field of a counter clockwise rotating vortex but I just can't seem to get its scalar field.

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Comment: Not every vector field is conservative. Say, in 2D, for the field $F=(P,Q)$ to be conservative, you need $Q_x=P_y$.

Comment: BTW, to get the potential, when it does exist, you do not just "integrate" both components. You need to compute the line integral from any fixed reference point (or do something similar).

Answer (score 1):

If $\hat F=-y\,\hat\imath+x\,\hat\jmath$ is a gradient field, then the corresponding scalar function $f$ satisfies

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -y \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x$$

Integrating both sides of the first equation with respect to $x$ gives

$$f(x,y) = -xy + g(y)$$

and differentiating this with respect to $y$ gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -x +\frac{dg}{dy} = x$$

We assumed $g$ is independent of $x$, so its derivative should also be independent of $x$. Yet here $\frac{dg}{dy}=2x$ so no such scalar $g$ exists. $\hat F$ is not a gradient field.

In contrast to the first example, if $\hat F=2x\,\hat\imath+2y\,\hat\jmath$, the same procedure yields

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x \implies f(x,y)=x^2+g(y) \implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{dg}{dy}=2y \implies g(y)=y^2+C \\
\implies f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is no scalar field. We have a scalar field V if $\nabla V=\vec{F}$. It can be shown the curl of any gradient is 0.

So if $\nabla \times \vec{F} \neq 0, \vec{F}$ has no scalar field.

This implies a test for whether $\vec{F}$ has a scalar field. In two dimensions, that means find $\partial F_y/\partial x-\partial F_x/\partial y$. If that is non-zero then there is no scalar field.